# Image loaded black

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

actually I'm new to game programming , I use SpriteKit for Graphics. when I loaded  my image , black screen showed . what is wrong?? below is my code  that wrote in  GameScene.swift.Also I put my_Image  in project[copy if needed] Thanks for your reply.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {   
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {      
        let  exampleNode=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "snakes & ladders.png")
        exampleNode.size=CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)
        exampleNode.anchorPoint=CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        exampleNode.position=CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height*0.25)
        self.addChild(exampleNode)      
    }
}
```

Comment: ok looks like you have 3 issues,  1, "snakes & ladders.png" is a terrible file name,  I would rename this to snakesAndLadders.png,  2, you should not specify the size of your sprite, let the system do that for you.  3, eliminate your anchor point and position code for now, work on just getting your item on the scene

Comment: KnightofDragon,I do as you said,yet it is black

Comment: Use `let  exampleNode=SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor.blue,size:CGSize(100,100))` instead of your image,  let's get something on the screen for you

Comment: it worked,but how can load an image to screen??can be something about resolution of image??

Comment: ok so we know the problem,  how are you putting your images in your project?  Are you using the xcassets folder?

Comment: Make sure your image isn't too big either. If the original image size (size you made the actual image) is too big, it might not be able to load, even though you're shrinking it down

Comment: Nik,size of PNG Image is  6.8 MB, is is big for loading??

Comment: What are the dimensions of it? FYI: When you tag someone, use the @ symbol before their username. For example, to properly tag Knight0fDragon, do this: @Knight0fDragon (I used this example so he would be alerted of your prior comment)

Comment: I forgot to add @, thanks for your reminding  @Nik :)

Comment: @knight0fdragon,first drag and drop image to project navigator, then put it in Xcassets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,Size of picture must be same as Scene, for example  want to set an background image for iPhone 5s , Resolution of 5s is  640x1136,so must set image size to 640 pixel width, 1136 px height.
Always remember two things:

1. if run project and there is  X-image,address of picture isn't correct
2. if there is just black Screen , there are some Issues with Resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into a weird bug where if only some of my images have @2x, @3x appended to the name for the different resolutions, the other images that do not have the @2x, @3x on them appear as black boxes.

Say I have two images in my project: Image1 and Image2. I'll have 3 separate files for Image1 to support higher resolution screens, so I'll actually have Image1.png, Image1@2x.png, and Image1@3x.png, but I'll only have Image2.png.

Now if I let iOS figure out which one to use based on the device the app is running on, Image2 will appear as a black box while Image1 will be correct.

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: I added an explanation - see above.

Comment: Good find, Classen!!! I have seen this, and simplified a project and all its graphics imports and never nailed down what caused the problem. This makes perfect sense, and matches what I was doing, I had a few of different sizes with different size extensions, but never connected that to the problem. You may well be spot on!

Comment: @claassenApps, sorry but I don't have any experience about photoshop, what does '@2x' mean??

Comment: There are 3 different screen resolutions needed to support the different sized iPhones. Therefore, we need to create 3 different sized images to fit those screens. If you have an image that is CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), then you need to have the image in 10x10 pixels (@1x), 20x20 pixels (@2x), and 30x30 pixels (@3x).